# Reload Page (F5) with Hash Values in Url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hash

How can I keep the `hash` value in the `url` and keep the tab or `div` open even after refreshing the page. Here is my sample code:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 jQuery(function($) {
  showTab(location.hash || "userView");
  $("#nav a").click(function() {
   var hash = this.getAttribute("href");
   if (hash.substring(0, 1) === "#") {
    hash = hash.substring(1);
   }
   window.location.hash = hash;
   showTab(hash);
   return false;
  });

  function showTab(hash) {
   $(".displayUsers").hide();
   switch (hash) {
    case "userView": ViewUsers(); break;
    case "userLogs": UserLogs(); break;
    case "addUser": AddUser(); break;
   }
  }

 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">
 <dl id="nav">
  <dt>
   <p>•<a href="#addUser" class="listLink"> ADD USER</a></p>
  </dt>
  <dt>
   <p>•<a href="#userLogs" class="listLink"> USER LOGS</a></p>
  </dt>
  <dt>
   <p>•<a href="#userView" class="listLink"> VIEW USERS</a></p>
  </dt>
 </dl>
</div>

<div id="addUser" class="displayUsers" hidden></div>
<div id="userLogs" class="displayUsers" hidden></div>
<div id="userView" class="displayUsers" hidden></div>
```

After refreshing the page, the `hash` value is being kept in the `url` but the currently active `div` are being set to default - hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better parse `hash` in `showTab` function. Main problem was, you were sending `hash` or `userView` but the `hash` there had `#` at the beginning. You parse it `onClick` but you don't parse it `onload`. So I moved parsing code into the `showTab` function.

```
showTab(location.hash || "userView");
$("#nav a").click(function() {
    var hash = this.getAttribute("href");
    showTab(hash);
    return false;
});

function showTab(hash) {

    if (hash.substring(0, 1) === "#") {
        hash = hash.substring(1);
    }
    window.location.hash = hash;
    $(".displayUsers").hide();
    switch (hash) {
        case "userView":
            ViewUsers();
            break;
        case "userLogs":
            UserLogs();
            break;
        case "addUser":
            AddUser();
            break;
    }
}

function ViewUsers() {
    $("#userView").show();
}

function UserLogs() {
    $("#userLogs").show();
}

function AddUser() {
    $("#addUser").show();
}
```

Working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/ergec/z02xzatj/